# Unsubscribed still receiving emails after opt-out

Tags: newsletter, opt-out

We have an issue here where a user opt-out from an email subscription and still is receiving newsletter.

anybody have seen this issue ?

Kind regards

Comment: There used to be something like where if it was scheduled before they opt-out it still sends to them. Check lab.civicrm.org there might still be some outstanding issues.

Comment: are you just using civimail, or some integration with mailchimp?

Comment: also your question asks about 'unsubscribed' and 'opt-out'. these terms refer to different situations